# Speeding up WHERE EXISTS clause by FETCH NEXT clause

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have a long running Oracle Query which uses a bunch of:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Table WHERE TableColumn IN (...))
```

Instead of using `SELECT NULL`, which goes through the entire table to find criteria, can't I just put `FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY` after it since I only care if `TableColumn` is `IN (...)`?

Like this:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Table WHERE TableColumn IN (...) FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY)
```

So the `WHERE EXISTS` would be evaluated quicker.

**EDIT:**

Below is the query plan without the `FETCH NEXT` clause attached:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation                     | Name            | Rows      | Bytes     | Cost   | Time |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                 |         1 |        75 | 521611 |      |
|  1 |   SORT AGGREGATE              |                 |         1 |        75 |        |      |
|  2 |    HASH JOIN                  |                 |    531266 |  39844950 | 521611 |      |
|  3 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         | ACCT            |     47574 |    523314 |    418 |      |
|  4 |     HASH JOIN                 |                 |    531224 |  33998336 | 521185 |      |
|  5 |      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN     | PK_ACTVTYP      |       454 |      2270 |      2 |      |
|  6 |      HASH JOIN                |                 |    531224 |  31342216 | 521177 |      |
|  7 |       INDEX FULL SCAN         | PK_ACTVCAT      |        67 |       335 |      1 |      |
|  8 |       HASH JOIN SEMI          |                 |    531224 |  28686096 | 521169 |      |
|  9 |        NESTED LOOPS SEMI      |                 |    531224 |  28686096 | 521169 |      |
| 10 |         STATISTICS COLLECTOR  |                 |           |           |        |      |
| 11 |          HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI |                 |    531224 |  25498752 | 112887 |      |
| 12 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL   | AMSACTVGRPEMPL  |      2364 |     35460 |     10 |      |
| 13 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL   | ACTV            |  12779986 | 421739538 | 112712 |      |
| 14 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN      | ACTVSUBACTV_DX2 | 163091724 | 978550344 | 251246 |      |
| 15 |        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN   | ACTVSUBACTV_DX2 | 163091724 | 978550344 | 251246 |      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below is the query plan with the `FETCH NEXT` clause attached:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation                      | Name            | Rows     | Bytes     | Cost   | Time |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                 |        1 |        69 | 113148 |      |
|  1 |   SORT AGGREGATE               |                 |        1 |        69 |        |      |
|  2 |    FILTER                      |                 |          |           |        |      |
|  3 |     HASH JOIN                  |                 |   531221 |  36654249 | 113144 |      |
|  4 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL         | ACCT            |    47574 |    523314 |    418 |      |
|  5 |      HASH JOIN                 |                 |   531179 |  30808382 | 112718 |      |
|  6 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN     | PK_ACTVTYP      |      454 |      2270 |      2 |      |
|  7 |       HASH JOIN                |                 |   531179 |  28152487 | 112710 |      |
|  8 |        INDEX FULL SCAN         | PK_ACTVCAT      |       67 |       335 |      1 |      |
|  9 |        HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI    |                 |   531179 |  25496592 | 112702 |      |
| 10 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL      | AMSACTVGRPEMPL  |     2167 |     32505 |     10 |      |
| 11 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL      | ACTV            | 12778893 | 421703469 | 112527 |      |
| 12 |     VIEW                       |                 |        1 |        13 |      4 |      |
| 13 |      WINDOW BUFFER PUSHED RANK |                 |        8 |        48 |      4 |      |
| 14 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN         | ACTVSUBACTV_DX2 |        8 |        48 |      4 |      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From what I see, it looks like without the `FETCH NEXT` it's adding overhead by more `TABLE ACCESS FULL`

**EDIT #2**

Adding `AND ROWNUM = 1` instead of `FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY`:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation                    | Name              | Rows     | Bytes     | Cost   | Time |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                   |        1 |        54 | 128114 |      |
|  1 |   SORT AGGREGATE             |                   |        1 |        54 |        |      |
|  2 |    FILTER                    |                   |          |           |        |      |
|  3 |     HASH JOIN                |                   | 12779902 | 690114708 | 113296 |      |
|  4 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL       | ACCT              |    47574 |    523314 |    418 |      |
|  5 |      HASH JOIN               |                   | 12778893 | 549492399 | 112713 |      |
|  6 |       MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN   |                   |    30418 |    304180 |     31 |      |
|  7 |        INDEX FULL SCAN       | PK_ACTVCAT        |       67 |       335 |      1 |      |
|  8 |        BUFFER SORT           |                   |      454 |      2270 |     30 |      |
|  9 |         INDEX FAST FULL SCAN | PK_ACTVTYP        |      454 |      2270 |      0 |      |
| 10 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL      | ACTV              | 12778893 | 421703469 | 112517 |      |
| 11 |     COUNT STOPKEY            |                   |          |           |        |      |
| 12 |      INLIST ITERATOR         |                   |          |           |        |      |
| 13 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN      | PK_AMSACTVGRPEMPL |        1 |        15 |      2 |      |
| 14 |     COUNT STOPKEY            |                   |          |           |        |      |
| 15 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN        | ACTVSUBACTV_DX2   |        2 |        12 |      4 |      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you analyzed the query with EXPLAIN PLAN to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I have, but I also want to speed up other parts also. I tested with Dummy data and adding in `FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY` to a couple of the `WHERE EXISTS` clauses has already saved me 100 sec.

Comment: `exists()` doesn't go through the entire table, it checks for the existence of any row - which is why it's better than counting and seeing it the count is greater than zero. The use of `in()` is more likely to be an issue, but you need to look at the execution plan to see what it's doing really.

Comment: @AlexPoole Why does adding `FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY` speed up the query then?

Comment: I don't know, because the data is already in the cache? One line of pseudocode isn't enough to go on.

Comment: What are you doing within the `IN` clause? Is there a subquery or a list of values?

Comment: @MickMnemonic List of values like `'ABC', 'AAA', 'BBB'`

Comment: Ok. Comparing the query plan with/without the row-limiting clause (`FETCH NEXT...`) should give you an idea about what (if anything) is different or if the speedup is because of a cache hit.

Comment: Interesting find with the execution plans. Just wondering, what would happen if you'd use an old Oracle shortcut using `rownum`, for getting the first row: `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Table WHERE TableColumn IN (...) AND rownum = 1)`

Comment: @MickMnemonic Putting `AND ROWNUM = 1` actually brought down the query from 300 sec to 90 sec.That's a big difference, why is that?

Comment: It's the `COUNT STOPKEY` operation in the plan. I don't know _why_ it's faster but basically adding `ROWNUM = 1` to any query will just return (up to) one (random) row from the result set (Tom Kyte [explains the concept in this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-rownum-and-limiting-results)). The behaviour your seeing here could be a result of many different things, including various optimizer options that have been enabled in your Oracle instance.

Comment: Strange. `EXISTS` should always stop looking once a record is found. Neither a `FETCH` clause nor a `ROWNUM` condition should have any effect. The subquery isn't even correlated. You should have an index on `TableColumn` of course - at least if `Table` is a big table.

Answer (score 0):

The `FETCH NEXT` is new in 12c, and to avoid the performance issue causing it add 
hint like below

```
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT /*+ first_rows(1)*/* FROM Table WHERE TableColumn IN (...) FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY)
```

try it and check its query plan

Note: I recommend to add indexes on table ACCT ,ACTV to enhance its performance.